# How do I display the latest post related to another?

Tags: 7, views

I'm on d7. I have 12 nodes that I use as groups with the entity relations module. When a user submits a post, they choose one of the groups to put it into. I want to make a views list of all 12 groups that displays the title of the latest post that has been submitted into each of them. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [views field view](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to get the job done.